# XSD - fixed values

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to represent the following data in xsd:

I have 4 principles. Each of them has from 1 to 4 subprinciples and each subprinciple has a guideline, a checker and a comment attributes, like this tree structure:

```
 1. Principle ONE

    a. subprinciple A

        1. guideline  
        2. checker 
        3. comment  

    b. subprinciple B
       ....

  2. Principle TWO
  3. Principle THREE
  4. Principle FOUR
```

In XML the representation is the following:

```
       <principle>
            <principle_name>principle_name0</principle_name>
            <guidelines_properties>
                <guideline>guideline0</guideline>
                <checker>false</checker>
                <comments>comments0</comments>
            </guidelines_properties>
            <guidelines_properties>
                <guideline>guideline1</guideline>
                <checker>false</checker>
                <comments>comments1</comments>
            </guidelines_properties>
        </principle>
        <principle>
            <principle_name>principle_name1</principle_name>
            <guidelines_properties>
                <guideline>guideline2</guideline>
                <checker>false</checker>
                <comments>comments2</comments>
            </guidelines_properties>
            <guidelines_properties>
                <guideline>guideline3</guideline>
                <checker>false</checker>
                <comments>comments3</comments>
            </guidelines_properties>
        </principle>
```

and in XSD I have defined it in this way:

```
  <xs:element name="principles">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="principle" minOccurs="4" maxOccurs="4"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="principle">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="principle_name"/>
            <xs:element ref="guidelines_properties" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="guidelines_properties">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="guideline"/>
            <xs:element ref="checker"/> 
            <xs:element ref="comments"/> 
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Here I think I have no problem. What I would like to do is to fix the value of the principles and the guidelines. Does anyone have an idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a facet that will enumerate the values.  If you enumerate exactly one value, then only one value will be allowable.

```
<xs:element name="car">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Audi"/> <!-- only "Audi" allowed -->
      <!-- <xs:enumeration value="Golf"/> -->
      <!-- <xs:enumeration value="BMW"/> -->
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: ok, but how can I set that for each principle there is a/some specific subprinciples (fixed values too)?

Comment: Just add the restriction to each type you want restricted.  XSD is a bit limited when it comes to conditional restrictions (i.e. allow subprinciple only if primary principle is "principle 1"). For that, you need a more expressive language, like [RelaxNG](http://relaxng.org/)

Comment: ... a more expressive language, like RelaxNG or XSD 1.1.

Comment: Point taken. I'm still not sure the overall support rate of XSD 1.1, though.  Last time I tried (admittedly a year ago), I had to jump through hoops to get XSD 1.1 support, and had to back it out for deployment. @MichaelKay is in a much better position to recommend well supported tools than I.

Comment: There are currently three XSD 1.1 processors (Xerces, Saxon, Altova) and it may well be true that there are practical barriers to adoption. However, I don't think that's an excuse for using "XSD" as a synonym for XSD 1.0, and describing the limitations of XSD 1.0 as if they were limitations of XSD in general.